# UDP packets not sending?

Tags: sockets, udp, ppp

I have a simple C program that binds a socket so that it can
receive and send UDP packets.  It uses `recvfrom` to receive packets, and
shortly after receiving one, it constructs and sends a reply
packet, using `sendto` in the obvious way, sending to the same
address and port that `recvfrom` reported.

This program worked perfectly in initial testing, when the
packets were coming in and going out over a regular Ethernet
interface, eth0.  But now I'm trying to use it over a PPP
interface, ppp0, and for some reason it's not working.

`sendto` is not reporting any errors, but tcpdump is not showing
the packets going out.  (It is showing the packets coming in, so
I'm pretty sure tcpdump is working.)

And I have an existing program that's doing essentially the same
thing, but it works properly under all circumstances, on all
interfaces.  I haven't yet worked out how the existing program
might be setting up its sockets or its send/receive logic
differently, that allows it to work while my new, simpler program
fails.

Some of the packets are large (approaching MTU), but plenty
of them are small (<100 bytes), and none of them are getting
through, so I don't think it's an MTU problem.

Can anyone think of anything that would cause a sent packet to fail to
go out in this way?  (I'm not saying it has anything to do with ppp in particular; that it fails under ppp for me may be a coincidence, or it may be a key part of the problem.)

Sorry I can't post the actual code; it's at work and I'm at home.
The relevant part looks something like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
char buf[1600];
int r, r2;

r = recvfrom(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen);

/* ... */

r2 = sendto(sock, buf2, n2, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, addrlen);
```

(If you need to see a more complete example, I can post that tomorrow.)

Answer (score 0):

**If none of traffic works:**

There could be routing problem. Check routing table of the host.

You can also check with tcpdump, that traffic is not going out via wrong interface. For example:

If you expect to see traffic in ppp0 by command:

> tcpdump -i ppp0 udp port 123

And you don't see the wanted traffic, then check other interfaces by similar command to ensure that traffic does not go out via wrong interface:

> tcpdump -i eth0 udp port 123

**If part of traffic works:**

If you are using some mobile network (often used via ppp0), then your uplink speed may be slower than downlink speed.

So a client may send more traffic to your server (via downlink), than uplink is capable to transfer.

Because UDP doesn't have such reliability and congestion/flow control like TCP have, UDP can discard some packets in overload situation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  What do you mean using tcpdump to check interface usage? I'm not familiar with that technique.

Comment: @Steve Summit : Example added to the answer. Nothing magical, maybe you have already done that.